# WPF Close Window Closes Source Window. Why?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

The problem that I am having is a little hard to describe, so please hear it out.

I'm simply opening one window from another and then trying to close the second one. If I use Command of the InputBindings of the second one, the second one closes fine. If I call the close directly it closes both the first and second window. I expect code will help is this scenario.

WPF: Window1View (key part)

```
<Grid>
  <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding RptKeyDownCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Window1ViewModel: (shortened for listing)

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
var _runCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Run(), () => CanRun());

    public void Run()
    {
        var v = new Window2();
        var vm = new Window2ViewModel();
        vm.RequestClose += v.Close;
        v.DataContext = vm;
        v.ShowDialog();
    }

    public event Action RequestClose;

    var _closeCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Close(), () => CanClose());
    public void Close()
    {
        if (RequestClose != null)
            RequestClose();
    }
```

WPF: Window2View

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
    <TextBox Text="Hello">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand 
                     Command="{Binding Close2Command, Mode=OneWay}"
                     PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

Window2ViewModel: (has the same Close Command plus EventToCommand end point)

```
var _close2Command = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(p => Close2(p), p => CanClose2(p));

    public void Close2(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            Close();               <- Here closes both Window1View and Window2View?
    }
```

Comment: I would say you'll need to post both vm and views... I have a suspicion that this is a event wiring issue but can't be sure without seeing the whole picture

Comment: You need to post more code, especially showing the event wiring. Does the call to close terminate your application?

Comment: I've created a solution that reproduces the problem. The key steps are click the Win1 button, then press Esc on Win2 (close properly), then click the hello textbox then press Esc (both now close?)<iframe title ="Preview" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" style="width:98px;height:115px;padding:0;background-color:#fcfcfc;" src="https://skydrive.live.com/embedicon.aspx/.Public?cid=da3e430c1a5f3b81&sc=documents"></iframe>

Comment: Apparently too much editing...The key steps are click the Win1 button, then press Esc on Win2 (close properly), then again steps 1 then click the hello textbox to get focus then press Esc (both windows now close?)

Comment: Obalix: It doesn't terminate the application when the parent is called from from yet another part. It just closes the current window (Window2View) and its parent (Window1View) so some unknown reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EventToCommand vs InputBindings Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605027/eventtocommand-vs-inputbindings-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605027/eventtocommand-vs-inputbindings-problem/6640909#6640909) on your other thread for a solution.

Comment: Yes, as this one was very confusing, I thought it best to clearly and cleanly re-describe the problem. Once you do that, the answer presents itself.

Answer (score 0):

From Window2ViewModel you should Call RequestClose not Close.

Here is the code for Window2ViewModel

```
RelayCommand _close2Command;
public ICommand Close2Command
{
    get
    {
        if (_close2Command == null)
        {
            _close2Command = new RelayCommand(param => CloseEx(), param => CanClose());
        }
        return _close2Command;
    }
}

public virtual void CloseEx()
{
    Close();
}

public event Action RequestClose;
public virtual void Close()
{
    if (RequestClose != null)
    {
        *RequestClose();*
    }
}
public virtual bool CanClose()
{
    return true;
}
```

Also Window1ViewModel should have code as :

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;           
var _runCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Run(), () => CanRun()); 
var vm;

public void Run()               
{                   
    var v = new Window2();                   
    vm = new Window2ViewModel();                   
    vm.RequestClose += CloseV2;                   
    v.DataContext = vm;                   
    v.ShowDialog();               
}                          

public event Action RequestClose;                          
var _closeCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Close(), () => CanClose());    

public void CloseV2()               
{                   
    vm.Close();              
}

public void Close()               
{                   
    if (RequestClose != null)                       
    RequestClose();               
}
```

Try to understand your code. 
Note in you code you are binding event of both V1.RequestClose to V2.RequestClose to same method Close. In my case I have them separate and V2.RequestClose will always call vm.Close.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I triple checked for that but trying to cut down the amount of code very likely made it look that way. Please see the link in the comment above where I create a new solution that reproduces the problem.